# React-Native - Beacon Manager - undefined is not an object

Tags: ios, react-native

I get an error if i use the following code. I have run a "pod install", link the library manually. Nothing works.

- React-Native Version: 0.69.0
- Library-Version: 1.0.7

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
    Text,
    TouchableOpacity, View
} from 'react-native';

// @ts-ignore
import {Beacons} from 'react-native-beacons-manager';


export default class App extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        Beacons.requestWhenInUseAuthorization();
        // Beacons.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
        // Beacons.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates(true);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={{color: 'white', top: 150}}>test</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
};
```

Does somebody know why the error occurs?

Comment: After i run "pod install" again, i get the error:

"Error: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager/lib/next/new.module.ios.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: `new NativeEventEmitter()` requires a non-null argument."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**IOS**

For IOS we need to link it manually. Follow next steps:

1. Drug `RNiBeacon.xcodeproj` from `node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager/ios` to `Libraries` folder in xcode

[image]

2. Link it to your binaries:

[image]

3. Add this path `"$(SRCROOT)/node_modules/react-native-beacons-manager/ios"` to Headers Search Paths for your App

[image]

4. Add this paths `$(SRCROOT)/../../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/React-Core`, `$(SRCROOT)/../../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/Yoga`, `$(SRCROOT)/../../../../ios/Pods/Headers/Public/YogaKit`
   to Headers Search Paths for RNiBeacon:

[image]

**Android**

This library doesn't support new versions of react native for Android. You need to use forks:
https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/issues/249

https://github.com/MacKentoch/react-native-beacons-manager/issues/228#issuecomment-964131282

https://github.com/benlui/react-native-beacons-manager

depends on your need

Comment: I tested it and i get the same error with both forks. I use iOS and i updated "react" to 18.0.0 and react-native to 0.69.7

The error are sill "ypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[8], "react-native-beacons-manager").Beacons.requestAlwaysAuthorization')"

I added to the package.json following:

- "react-native-beacons-manager": "git://github.com/Hamilton-Robson/react-native-beacons-manager.git"

And after this test i added

- "react-native-beacons-manager": "git://github.com/dmontecillo/react-native-beacons-manager.git"

Comment: i run pod install after a "npm install". 
Does you know whats wrong?

Comment: try to use this fork https://github.com/benlui/react-native-beacons-manager

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this. But still with an error. I get "Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code" - "'syscall' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 10.0 - syscall(2) is unsupported; please switch to a supported interface. For SYS_kdebug_trace use kdebug_signpost()."

My deploy version is iOS 13.0

Maybe some version issues there? Or do you know how i can fix the error?

Comment: I have tried to remove my Pod and clean the project. After that i run "pod install". But the error is still there

Comment: @user3625778 check my updated answer, I've added section about ios

Comment: I will try that and reply to you, thanks. Should i use for iOS also a fork or the „original“ library?

Comment: Depends on your need, do you need to support android, if yes take fork for android if no you can use original version

Comment: Now I had time to test this. So I created a new, fresh app. Then I added react-native-beacons-manager and followed the steps you mentioned. First of all thanks for that. However, I still have the error. "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[8], "react-native-beacons-manager").Beacons.requestAlwaysAuthorization')"

Comment: I use the 1.0.7 version for the beacons-library

Comment: I tested only with `requestWhenInUseAuthorization `

Comment: @user3625778 just checked and it works fin on my setup. I think if you run yarn or npm install after the changes I described in my answer you remove them, please check settings in xcode. If you want to keep this setting create patch for them with patch-package

Comment: Please tell me what versions you are using please :)

Comment: Pod, npm, node, react, react-native, ios :)

Comment: "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-beacons-manager": "^1.0.7",

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250362/discussion-between-kirill-novikov-and-user3625778).